# Enable button function inside backgroundWorker

Tags: button, c++-cli

I am using windows form application to create gui. I have create a form with several button. The functionality of the first button called button1 is to read a video from hard disk and display it to a picturebox. The last line of button1 code is to enable another button:

```
 button2->Enabled = true;
```

Button1 code is inside a backgroundworker. The result of this, it works fine, however it doesnt enable the button2. Is there issue using button properties inside backgroundworker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use BeginInvoke method and use Action delegate because backgroundworker DoWork doesn't modify UI.

```
private:
   void DoWork(Object^ /*sender*/, EventArgs^ /*e*/ )
   {
      // some code
      button2->BeginInvoke(gcnew Action(this, &MyForm::ModifyButton) );
   }

   void ModifyButton()
   {
      button2->Enabled = true;
   }
```